Create map with solid color in QGis
I want to create a map in QGis that only contains the names of the cities, but is otherwise one solid color, e.g. red background for the map and yellow font color. I have downloaded the quick map service and importet a KMZ file from Google's MyMap. However, if I click on the layer's settings and choose colorize, I struggle to archieve what I want.
